# Know if script is starts with root rights

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to know if a script has been start with root rights?

At the beginning I would to do something like this :

```
import ...

print('Welcome')

if_start_with_sudo:
    ...
else:
    print('This program must be start as root')
    exit()
```

It is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Python `os` module's `geteuid()`. According to [its documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#process-parameter):

> Return the current process’s effective user id.

Considering that the `root` user's UID is always 0, you just need to check if `os.geteuid()` returns 0:

```
if os.geteuid() == 0:
    # UID is 0, your program is being run by the root user
```